# CSS Float not working

Tags: html, css

I can't get this working.. It seems so obvious but I'm having a problem here! I can't line two divs! I want one to have a specific width (300px) and the other to fill up the space.

My issue: http://jsfiddle.net/4qU4y/

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.red {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="red">RED</div>
<div class="blue">BLUE</div>
```

Comment: have a `float: left` on your `.red`

Comment: [Put the blue one first](http://jsfiddle.net/4qU4y/1/). OMG it works!

Comment: How does what @NiettheDarkAbsol suggested not work? Have you seen the Fiddle?

Comment: My mistake, but how does this work? What's the difference??

Comment: Either blue first, or within red: http://jsfiddle.net/7B6P6/

Comment: What's the difference? If you put the red one first, then the blue one can just chill out where it is. Put the blue one first, and it will float on the right with the red one making room for it.

Comment: `the blue one can just chill out where it is` = +1

Answer (score 0):

You should float the other div as well. And as a certain div has 100% it will never float. Try:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.red {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: red;
    float: left
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
}
```